# Comparing String,if it is NULL in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using the following code to compare a string if it is equal to NULL in a Stored Procedure in Sql Server 2008.

```
IF(Name != '')
    // Do some stuff
ELSE IF(Phone != '')
    // Do some stuff
ELSE
    // Do some other stuff
```

Is there any disadvantages or drawback's in using the above format of Checking a string.

I was using the below code before:

```
IF(Name IS NOT NULL)
    // Do some stuff
ELSE IF(Phone IS NOT NULL)
    // Do some stuff
ELSE
    // Do some other stuff
```

which is not working as expected.

Comment: This would imply that the data is empty string, and not null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!=/<> ''` is not the same as `IS NOT NULL`! You need this:

```
IF(Name <> '')
    // Do some stuff
ELSE IF(Phone  <> '')
    // Do some stuff
ELSE
    // Do some other stuff
```

If `Name` or `Phone` can be `NULL`, you need this:

```
IF(ISNULL(Name, '') <> '')
    // Do some stuff
ELSE IF(ISNULL(Phone, '')  <> '')
    // Do some stuff
ELSE
    // Do some other stuff
```

In SQL, `NULL` is always `<> ''`. In fact, in most configurations, `NULL` is also `<> NULL`.

Comment: What do you mean "the same stuff"? If you want to compare *any* field/variable in SQL to *anything*, you mostly need to account for the case that the field/variable can be `NULL`. You could do something like `IF (ISNULL(datefield, CONVERT(DateTime, '20140101')) <> CONVERT(DateTime, '20140101') ...`.

Comment: sorry, "the same stuff" means comparing the DateTime datafield if its NULL or not. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

They are different: if `Name` is `NULL` it will never be *equal to*, or *not equal* to `''` because nothing is equivalent to `NULL`.

The only way to test for `NULL` is with `IS NULL`.

If you want to test for `NULL` *or* `''` then: `IF ISNULL(val, '') = ''`